# How to reduce the load on the master database with an additional database which is having real live data?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, elasticity

We are having an e-commerce application which is working in Mysql and java. We are expecting number of users increasing and our database is will be busy with our e-commerce request itself.

At the same time we are planing to implement a CRM tool to maintain our sales team which will again going to hit the same database and the database will again be more busy since we will have highly complex queries in our CRM tool.

The Mysql database we are having in an Amazon RDS server.

Is there any option for our CRM tool got the live data which read and write this data without affecting our original E-commerce database.

Let me know what all solutions we have in this case.

Comment: *"How to reduce the load on the master database with an additional database which is having real live data?"* This question is way to broad to be answerd directly.. The MySQL manual [Chapter 17 Replication](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication.html) seams to be about what you want..  But really consider hiring a DBA to set it up..

Comment: .. also Amazon RDS seams to be talking about [Replication](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/faqs/) here

Comment: .. besides that no idea how that replication is going to behave as we have no idea what is running on the server and which MySQL configuration is used..

Comment: Are you suggesting me to use a master slave configuration? i mean master DB for E-commerce and slave DB for CRM? If i configure like that will my CRM have the write permission to the slave DB?

Comment: replication or [MySQL Cluster](https://www.mysql.com/products/cluster/) is about the only choice..  *"If i configure like that will my CRM have the write permission to the slave DB?"*   that would mean a `master slave - master slave` configuration as i assume when the CRM tool makes change that other DB (original E-commerce) also needs to be updated on some tables?

Comment: But like i said before consider hiring a DBA, let him/her take a look into the data and plans, and see what him/her advice is.. With this limitted information we can't give a solid advice or suggestion for that matter..

Comment: If you need i can provide you more information. Let me know what all configuration information you need.